# How to import csv file into mysql database using express js and sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I want to import csv file data into mysql database table I can do it using only mysql query but I am not able to do it by sequelize  and express js please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use seeders. see the docs here on making and running seeds http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/migrations.html#creating-first-seed

you also need to convert your CSV to SQL. see here https://blog.sqlizer.io/posts/convert-csv-to-sql/

The format for RAW SQL in your seeder is listed below

```
module.exports = {
  up: queryInterface => queryInterface.sequelize.query(`
      // RAW QUERY HERE
  `),
};
,,,
```